# Dummit and Foote page 526

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I'm having trouble with a line of example 2 on page 526.

Consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. generated over $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$. Since $\sqrt{3}$  is of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$,  the degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ ***is at most $2$*** and is precisely $2$ iff $ x^2 - 3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

Why is it at most two?
From the previous page we know that
$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2 , \sqrt 3) : \mathbb{Q} \sqrt 2][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2 ) : \mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2 , \sqrt 3) : \mathbb{Q}]$

Can I somehow use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\{1,\sqrt 3\}$ spans $K(\sqrt{3})/K$ for any field $K$, so as a vector space, $K(\sqrt{3})/K$ has dimension at most $2$.

Here $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ since $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{3})=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Thanks Alex this is an explanation which I find intuitive, can you elaborate on how the irreducibility of x^2 - 3 changes affects things?

Comment: @fourier1234 It doesn't change anything in my answer, as my statement (with $2$ replaced by $n$) holds for any root of any polynomial of degree $n$. However, because in this case $x^2-3$ *is* irreducible over $K$, we know that the set $\{1,\sqrt3\}$ is linearly independent so the degree is precisely $2$.

Comment: I never knew that relationship existed, why is this true?

Comment: @fourier1234 That adjoining a root of an $n$th degree polynomial gives an extension of degree at most $n$?

Comment: Sorry no, that the irreducibility implies linear independence

Comment: @fourier1234 Suppose we have some linear dependence between the powers of the root $r$ of $f(x)$, say $c_kr^k+\cdots+c_1r+c_0=0$. Then $r$ is a root of $g(x)=c_kx^k+\cdots+c_1x+c_0$, so $r$ is a root of $\gcd(f(x),g(x))$, thus $\gcd(f(x),g(x))$ is a nontrivial factor of $f(x)$, contradicting irreducibility.

Comment: For the last sentence are you using that if two polynomials share a root they must share at least a linear factor?

Comment: @fourier1234 Yes.

Answer (score 2):

It is at most $2$ because the quadratic polynomial $f(x) = x^2 - 3 \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}][x]$ has a root in the field extension.  Worst case scenario, $f(x)$ is irreducible, which would mean that the field extension is degree $2$.  Otherwise, if the polynomial was reducible, then it would be a (trivial) degree $1$ extension.

The important think to note is that, given a field extension $F[\alpha]$ over $F$, the degree of that field extension will be exactly the degree of the minimal (irreducible) polynomial in $F[x]$ with $\alpha$ as a root.

Comment: So is this relying on Q(sqrt 2 , sqrt 3 ) =( Q(sqrt 2)) (sqrt 3), so in your explanation F = Q(sqrt 3 )

Comment: In my second paragraph, $F = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ in this case.  Whether the extension from $F$ to $F[\sqrt{3}]$ is degree 1 or 2 basically comes down to whether the minimal polynomial in $F[x]$ with $\sqrt{3}$ as a root is a degree 1 or degree 2.

Answer (score 0):

When you add an algebraic element $r$ to a field $F$, the degree of the extension equals the degree of the minimum polynomial of $r$ over $F$. The minimum polynomial is a factor of any polynomial $f(X)\in F[X]$ such that $f(r)=0$.

In this case $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $r=\sqrt{3}$ and $f(X)=X^2-3$.